# Convert nested dictionary into dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

My dictionary looks like this

```
mydict = 
{240594.0: {1322.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1323.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1324.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1325.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1326.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1327.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1328.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1329.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1356.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1357.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1358.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1359.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1360.0: 1.6900000000000002, ...},

226918.0: {1322.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1323.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1324.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1325.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1326.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1327.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1328.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1329.0: 1.6899999999999999, 1352.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1353.0: 1.6900000000000002, 1354.0: 1.6899999999999999 ...}}
```

which is the real value of `{iri_key: {week:price, week:price ...}, iri_key: {...}}`
and I want to convert this dictionary into dataframe which looks like

```
         week week  week ...
irikey: price price price ...
irikey: ...    ...   ...
```

in above case

```
           1322.0                  ...
240594.0   1.6899999999999999      ...
226918.0   1.6900000000000002      ...
```

how could I do this?

Comment: Do you know the range of `week`?

Comment: yes from 1322 to 1373

Comment: but some of them has missing values so dimension doesn't match. still max of week is 1373 and min is 1322

Comment: you could complete the dict by replace missing values to some invalid value like -1

Comment: Actually pandas can take incomplete dict to construct dataframe, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have probably discovered, `DataFrame(mydict)` is valid code. You could simply take the transpose (`.T`) to get your desired result.

A better way, in terms of code readability and directness, is available: use the specific DataFrame constructor `DataFrame.from_dict`, which has a keyword argument `orient`.

```
In [2]: DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')
Out[2]: 
        1356  1357  1358  1359  1360  1322  1323  1324  1325  1326  1327  \
226918   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69   
240594  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69   

        1328  1329  1352  1353  1354  
226918  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  1.69  
240594  1.69  1.69   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[2 rows x 16 columns]
```

As you can see from the example data you provided, missing values and variable lengths are handled properly.